# Элемент массива сразу после вызова фунции

Tags: массивы, php

Ребят, есть такой код

```
$data = unserialize($array)[$id];
```

Как вы поняли, он должен создать массив и сразу же я пытаюсь вывести элемент массива из него.
На локалхосте все получается, но как только залил на сервер, то выдает ошибку о неожиданном знаке `[`

Comment: Не стоит так делать. `unserialize` может вернуть абсолютно любой тип данных. Всегда стоит проверять, что данные именно те, которые ожидаются, иначе просто получаем бомбу в коде, которая в любой момент сможет убить всю систему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая возможность - достать элемент из возвращаемого функцией массива - появилась только в PHP 5.3 или даже 5.4

Comment: 5.4 и выше, к сожалению.

Comment: Ну, ничего, 5.4, по-моему, по стабильности ничуть не проигрывает  предшественнику. Сам тестирую на 5.4, но новыми экзотеческими конструкциями не пользуюсь - для совместимости.

Comment: пыха к жабаскрипту приближается?)

Comment: @mountpoint, пыха приближается к человеческому поведению

Comment: @Fike то-есть к Рубину : )))

Comment: @mayar, @mountpoint, давайте обойдемся без этих комментариев.

Comment: @Fike, чего вы все такие злые?

Comment: Да, в этом плане - приближается. Откровенно говоря, и я не понимаю, зачем было так затягивать с очевидной и логичной конструкцией языка.